# IntelliJ IDEA thinks part of my project is subversion instead of git, how to fix this?

Tags: android, git, svn, intellij-idea

I have an Android project in IDEA, and added a module for testing.
This module is created within the directory of the App module itself.

Since I have done that, IDEA thinks that the files in the 'test' module are under subversion version control. However, I don't know why and how, as there wis no .svn directory, and I didn't do anything. I want to add this directory to my GIT of the whole project, but even though I added the files using the GIT command line tool, IDEA only gives me subversion commands.

When I try to add files using GIT I get a error message:

> svn: E155004: Cannot lock working copy '/': permission denied.

I don't really now what to do next, so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Check your project configuration in `Settings > Version Control`.

This is where your directory/vcs mappings are configured. Remove any SVN mapping that could exists, and make sure that the whole project is mapped to Git.
BTW, I don't know how this could have happened.

Comment: On Mac it is "IntelliJ IDEA | Preferences | Version Control".

Comment: Don't know the cause, but yes, for tests it says Subversion. I removed that and I think it works fine now! Thanks!

Comment: I have a similar problem, whenever I add a new folder to an existing project it is added as being managed by subversion so I have to fix it every time form settings -> version control.

Comment: Same problem still with 14.0.2. Youtrack bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-115100

Comment: I see this problem when some projects/modules are under `svn` and some under `git`. Once I remove the projects in conflicting VCS, IntelliJ reverts back to the VCS the project is configured with.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the settings are changed in the later versions of Intellej, but I couldn't find any "mapping" options.
I could resolve the issue by opening .idea/vcs.xml file and changing vcs value from "svn" to "Git".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="VcsDirectoryMappings">
    <mapping directory="" vcs="Git" />
  </component>
</project>
```

Answer (score -1):

Ctrl + Alt + S, then Version Control.