# How to avoid new Maven modules managed by other VCS than Subversion to be marked as managed by Subversion

Tags: git, svn, intellij-idea, intellij-15

I have a multi-module Maven project version controlled with Git. The source was initially cloned outside of IntelliJ IDEA, and then imported as a Maven project.

Initially, everything is properly seen as version controlled by Git. However, when I add a new Maven module and choose to *import changes* (i.e. reload the changes caused by the new *pom.xml* file), the module is marked as version controlled by Subversion (in *File* -> *Settings* -> *Version Control*):

[image: Subversion in Git project]

In the above picture, the first row is the Git root, and the second one is the newly created sub-module. The sub-module is located in a sub-folder to the Git root. To get IDEA to properly understand this (that the files actually are handled by Git), I need to manually remove the *Subversion* row.

Why does IDEA act like this despite the fact that Subversion hasn't been involved at all. Is there a setting that controls this?

I am running IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior appears to be described in JetBrains's ticketing system YouTrack as [IDEA-115110](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-115100), which is still open as of this writing. (I found this ticket by seeing it referenced in the comments of the accepted answer on [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20503669/65839).)

The comments of the YouTrack say that an available workaround (if you don't need Subversion support for other projects) is disabling the Subversion plugin altogether. (In Settings, go to the Plugins panel, uncheck Subversion Integration, and restart IntelliJ IDEA.)

You could also try voting for and/or commenting on that JetBrains ticket, to describe any triggering circumstances you can discover and to let JetBrains know that you'd like the issue addressed. If you have a support contract with JetBrains, you may want to contact them via that approach as well.